# How to get Adafruit Bluefruit LE input on Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth-lowenergy

I made a project on Unity and an Adafruit Bluefruit LE with sensors for the interactivity. My Bluefruit works great, it sends a string constructed with a single character representing the sensor (between A and F) and the analog value get from the same sensor.

The output looks like this: `A12`, `B3`, `F68`, ...

On Unity, I would like to get this string and parse it by myself, knowing the structured string made this simple to do. But, I cannot get the input string from the BLE on Unty, it always returns an empty string.

I tried this with no luck:

```
string sensorString = Input.inputString;
```

Because I'm not sending a single character, I cannot use function like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.B)) { ... }
```

The output debug from the BLE shows me the output string, and if I try with an app to write (like TextEdit) on my MBP or iPad, the string is correctly written.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to get everything working, I hashed the string on the Bluefruit LE and send each chars one with an ending char.

Then on Unity I recompose the message and detect the ending char.